# Why does my shell command to push commits to multiple repos not push?

Tags: git, shell

I created Git `remote` to push commits to a Github repository (github) and to a `bare` repository (droplet) that automatically deploy code to `/var/www/myapp` thanks to Git `hooks`.

The idea is to enter `git push droplet` and `git push github` to push commits in the server (droplet) and to the central repo (github).

Now, when I enter `git push droplet` it push the commits to the server but when I enter `git push github` it says there is nothing to commit because the branch is up-to-date, but it's not. I checked the Github repository and see that the last commit is 4 months old.

How could I update the code base in my Github account ?

**Git remote**

```
$ git remote -v
droplet admin@droplet-myapp:/home/admin/repo/MyApp.git (fetch)
droplet admin@droplet-myapp:/home/admin/repo/MyApp.git (push)
github  git@github.com-MyApp:MyApp/MyApp.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com-MyApp:MyApp/MyApp.git (push)
```

**Git config**

```
$ more config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "github"]
        url = git@github.com-MyApp:MyApp/MyApp.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
[user]
        name = MyApp
        email = florent@myapp.com
[branch "master"]
[remote "droplet"]
        url = admin@droplet-myapp:/home/admin/repo/MyApp.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/droplet/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = droplet
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

**Git push** (which fail to update codebase)

```
$ git add . && git commit -m 'fix' && git push github
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'droplet/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies in this line

```
git add . && git commit -m 'fix' && git push github
```

You are trying to stage files. Than if this succeeded - commit files. And than if commit succeeded - push them to github.

Since you already committed you changes previously git commit fails, and push is not executed.

Use only `git push github` instead.